# AWS Java SDK - sending a SAML request to STS - Unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send a SAML request to AWS STS to get temporary credentials that I can use for authentication with other AWS services. Below is my code:

```
BasicAWSCredentials basicCreds=new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");

AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicCreds)).withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION.getName()).build();
AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest samlReq = new AssumeRoleWithSAMLRequest();
samlReq.setRoleArn(role_arn);
samlReq.setPrincipalArn(principal_arn);
samlReq.setSAMLAssertion(assertion);
AssumeRoleWithSAMLResult token = stsClient.assumeRoleWithSAML(samlReq);
```

The request needs to go through a proxy and I have already set that up in the code. When I run it, I am seeing the below error:

```
INFO: Configuring Proxy. Proxy Host: xxx.xxx.com Proxy Port: 9400
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1201)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1147)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1719)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1686)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1675)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRoleWithSAML(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:817)
    at com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRoleWithSAML(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:788)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:338)
```

This is happening at the line `AssumeRoleWithSAMLResult token = stsClient.assumeRoleWithSAML(samlReq);`. I understand that this error happens when a server certificate is absent in the cacerts file. I am running the code from my local laptop, so it's my own cacerts file that is being used.

Now, I am wondering if I must be adding the Proxy server certificate or AWS certificate ? If I should be adding the AWS certificate, where can I get that from? Is there any other workaround for this problem?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi Hemanth,
Did you found any solution for this ?.